# Function apply to three dimensions list

Tags: function-construction

I defined a function

```
f[x_, y_] := {x - y, x + y}
```

and I have a list

```
d1 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
```

I know how to input the list in a simple way,

```
f @@ Transpose[d1]
```

return

```
{{-1, -1, -1}, {3, 7, 11}}
```

But I don't know how to apply a high dimensions list, for example,

```
d2 = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 2}, {3,
  4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}};
```

Is there a simple way return results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f @@@ Transpose /@ d2
```

> {{{-1, -1, -1}, {3, 7, 11}}, {{-1, -1, -1}, {3, 7, 
>      11}}, {{-1, -1, -1}, {3, 7, 11}}, {{-1, -1, -1}, {3, 7, 11}}}

Comment: Thank you, it is a good way.

Answer (score 4):

You can extend the definition of `f` to accommodate data like `d2`:

```
fx = (Transpose[#] &) /* Apply[f]
```

Then evaluating `fx /@ d2` produces:

> ```
> { {{-1, -1, -1}, {3, 7, 11}}, {{-1, -1, -1}, {3, 7, 11}}, 
>      {{-1, -1, -1}, {3, 7, 11}}, {{-1, -1, -1}, {3, 7, 11}} }
> ```

Or you can simply use the third argument of [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) to apply the provided function at a desired level in an expression eg.

```
Apply[f, d2, {2}]
```

evaluates to

> ```
> { {{-1, 3}, {-1, 7}, {-1, 11}}, {{-1, 3}, {-1, 7}, {-1, 11}}, 
>      {{-1, 3}, {-1, 7}, {-1, 11}}, {{-1, 3}, {-1, 7}, {-1, 11}} }
> ```

which is identical to what you get if you evaluate `fx /* Transpose /@ d2`.

### A side note

The definition of `f` takes two parameters and outputs a list of two elements.

It would make sense (to my mind, at least) to expect that when `f` is applied on a list of pairs of elements, the output would be a list of pairs of elements.

In that sense, using `Transpose` in the first place in order to supply the proper number of arguments to `f` seems counterintuitive. It is definitely not wrong or something that doesn't evaluate or anything of that sort but it can cause complications.

Using the level specification in `Apply` seems a good way to apply `f` on data in deeper levels.